# can element using ng-repeat access variable created by ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

is this valid  for `ng-repeat` in angularjs 1.7.x

```
<div 
  ng-repeat="item in items"
  ng-class="item.id">
    {{tab.label}}
</div>
```

I am confused with the usage of variable created by ng-repeat ie `item` in the element which it is attached to. I thought we can use it inside that element only.

**I have checked that this works** but wanted to understand if there is any example in documentation for this case.

As an extension to this , does `ng-controller` works the same way for keys attached to `$scope`.

*Kindly give some reference as i have checked for `ng-repeat` that it works, i just want to understand why( or that it is the expected behavior)*

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates new scope that extends parent scope for each generated element. And adds $index and item variables to each.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov yes,, i just wanted to know if the values in the scope are available on the element also. What i thought was i can access values in scope inside the element and not on the element itself , that is the clarification i wanted , with reference